# Scalabe Log management with visualization and anomaly detection

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, data-visualization, elastic-stack, anomaly-detection

Currently, I am in the tools/stack deciding phase for a project.

Objectives:

```
- Log aggregation from over 200 servers with around 200 million transactions per day. So, the stack must be highly scalable.
- Data visualization/Dashboard like number of users hitting a particular page etc.
- Anomaly detection to predict server failures in advance.
- Preferably open source stack
```

As there are a lot of tools and stacks available in the market for log management, can somebody guide me in the right direction for my use-case and requirements.

I am thinking of opting ELK stack but not sure about its scalability to more than 200 servers and also I am doubtful about the anomaly detection on top of ELK stack. Any better open source option than ELK stack?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elastic has just released a beta X-Pack for Machine Learning mainly for . Read some insights about how it will help you with anomaly detection: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-machine-learning-for-the-elastic-stack + https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/first-look-elastics-new-machine-learning-technology-robert-cowart

Comment: Thanks. I will have a check. Seems like a good option as it is based on Prelert.

Comment: @SaurabhPant have you found any?